# Regular expression: sequences

Tags: regex, vb.net, sequence

Stuck with a silly problem. I have an input field, where user can input limited amount of letters (ABCDEFG). Here is the problem: I do not want users to be able to have more than 3 A, C, E and G's letters in a single subsequence of the input, that is: no AAA, CCC, EEE, GGG. And the second thing is almost the same as the first one: no more than 1 B, D, F in a single subsequence, that is: no BB, DD, FF. These two rules are somehow to be combined together.

So, for example, AABFGECC is valid. GEFFFAABG is invalid.

Hope, you will help me! Thank you!

P.S If it is important, I am writing my app in Visual Basic. But I think, this is not so important.

Comment: no `AAA` is actually "no more than 2", not 3... Is this VB.Net, by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could be clever and use back-references, a simple solution is to black-list the invalid sequences using a [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!.*(?:AAA|CCC|EEE|GGG|BB|DD|FF))[A-G]*$
```

Logically, that is the same has having those 7 invalid sequences in a list, and checking the string does not contain either one, which also gives you a nice alternative.

Comment: What if I write BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB ? Will it pass ? It should not.

Comment: @Dmitri - It contains a "BB", so it shall not. Look at how negative lookaheads work - if it *does* find "BB", it will *not match* the string.

Answer (score 2):

What if you made an expression which matches the cases you want to avoid and instead check that the input does not match? Like this:

```
([^A-F]|AAA|CCC|EEE|GGG|BB|DD|FF)
```